# Firebase keep user logged in when navigating to other pages

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm currently able to log in to my user account and successfully navigate to my dashboard while still logged in, but when I go to any other page, my login status is gone. Another issue is when updating my user's info, how can I write the function so that it's updating the info based on who's logged in? I have provided my code below. Thanks!

Edit profile JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth()

auth.onAuthStateChanged( auth,user => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      alert("User active: ");

      // User is signed in.
      var email = user.email;
      var uid = user.uid;

      //Take user to a different or home page
      window.location.href ="editprofile.html?id=" + uid;
    
    } else {
      alert("No active user please signup or sign in.");

      window.location.href ="login.html?error";

    }
});

var studioName, email, password, firstName, lastName, address, country, state, city, zip, phoneNumber;

function updateStu() {

    //Get data
    studioName = document.getElementById("studioName").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    password =  document.getElementById("password").value;
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;

    console.log(studioName, firstName, email);

    firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/studiopick/studio/users" + studioName)
    .update({
        
    //studioName : studioName,
    firstName : firstName,
    lastName : lastName,
    email : email,
    password : password,
    address : address,
    country : country,
    state : state,
    city : city,
    zip : zip,
    phoneNumber : phoneNumber
    });

    document.getElementById("studioName").value ="";
    document.getElementById("email").value ="";
    document.getElementById("password").value ="";
    document.getElementById("firstName").value ="";
    document.getElementById("lastName").value ="";
    document.getElementById("address").value ="";
    document.getElementById("country").value ="";
    document.getElementById("state").value ="";
    document.getElementById("city").value ="";
    document.getElementById("zip").value ="";
    document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value ="";

    alert("Data Updated");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

You are using the `auth.currentUser` property instead of the `user` returned from `onAuthStateChanged`

As per [The Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

If `user` is returned successfully from `onAuthStateChanged` you can set the value of the returned user globally to access it throughout the app. Otherwise you can navigate to /login (or equivalent).

For your second question:
This depends on how you structured your database. It’s common practice to use the Firebase Auth Id as the users/ which can then be referenced from user.uid.

If you would like to keep record of who created or last edited a document you can keep fields that contain the users id.

Firestore also has [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) which leverage [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to secure the database CRUD operation.